# Difference between Exception and JSONException in try-catch

Tags: android, exception

I am confused about using the different `Exception` terms in `Try-Catch`.
What could be the "disadvantage" of using simple `Exception` instead of `JSONException`?

#### Simple Exception

```
try {
  //...
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### JSONException

```
try {
  //...
}catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this not enough? https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException If not doing anything outside of catchable with jsonexception, then equivalent. if more code, then generic exception would catch that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception` is the base `class` for all exceptions `IOException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `FileNotFoundException`, `NullPointerException`, `JSONException` etc

If you are using your `try/catch` as shown below:

```
 try {
          //...
       }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

All the above mentioned `exceptions` will get caught and in case of any of these exceptions your `catch` block will get `executed/called`.

But if you use the `try/catch` as shown below:

```
try {
          //...
       }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Your `catch` block will get `called/executed` only if there is a `JSONException`.

If there is any other type of Exception for ex `NullPointerException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` etc then your `catch` block will not get called.

Hope this clears your doubt/question.